# How to validate this data entry form in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am new ASP.NET WebForms developer and I am struggling with validating a Data Entry Form. I should use the server-side validation only and it has to be using pure C#. I am wondering if there is a best approach to validate the following form instead of have multiple nested if-else statement which makes confusion and makes the code very difficult to understand.

ASP.NET Form:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Type</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Category</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategory" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Item</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-10">

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Issue</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-10">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtIssue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Suggestion</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-10">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSuggestion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>

                </div>



                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Reference</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-10">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReference" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Priority</label>

                    <div class="col-xs-10">

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPriority" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

                    </div>

                </div>

</div>
```

My current approach of validating the form is by using if-else statements such as:

```
 string type = string.Empty;

            string category = string.Empty;

            string issue = string.Empty

            string suggestion = string.Empty;

            string Reference = string.Empty;





            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtType.Text))

    {

        type = txtType.Text.Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCategory.Text))

        {

                            category = txtCategory.Text.Trim();

                            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtIssue.Text))

                            {

                               issue = txtIssue.Text.Trim();

                               if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSuggestion.Text))

                               {

                                  suggestion = txtSuggestion.Text.Trim();

                            try

                            {

                            //to do the operation

                            }

                            catch (Exception ex)

                            {

                                            throw ex;

                            }

                               }

                               else

                               {

                                  lblMessage.CssClass = "text-error";

                                  lblMessage.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode("Please fill out the Suggestion!");                    

                               }

                            }

                            else

                            {

                               lblMessage.CssClass = "text-error";

                               lblMessage.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode("Please fill out the Issue!");

                            }

        }

        else

        {

            lblMessage.CssClass = "text-error";

            lblMessage.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode("Please fill out the Category!");

        }

    }

    else

    {

        lblMessage.CssClass = "text-error";

        lblMessage.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode("Please fill out the Type!");

    }
```

It works well but I think it is lengthy and it makes confusion and makes the code very difficult to understand. **Could you please help me by showing me the best and right approach to validate all the inputs (or data entry) before doing the operation?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ASP.NET validation controls from the Visual Studio toolbox:

> RequiredFieldValidator
>
> CompareValidator
>
> RangeValidator
>
> RegularExpressionValidator
>
> CustomValidator
>
> DynamicValidator
>
> ValidationSummary
>
> From [Exploring ASP.NET Validation Controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512130413/https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426761/Exploring-ASP-NET-Validation-Controls)

My recommendation: the RequiredFieldValidator Control, which checks to see if the data is entered for the input control. You can have a RequiredFieldValidator control for each form element on which you wish to enforce the Mandatory Field rule.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" Style="top: 98px;
        left: 367px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 162px" ErrorMessage="password required"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

See also: [How to use the ASP.NET Validation Control to validate the user input](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2009/09/09/how-to-use-the-asp-net-validation-control-to-validate-the-user-input.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Consider using model validation.
For example:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```