# problem with duplicate values check in the edit page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I make checks of some values es (email) that cannot be duplicated in the database, these I have also in the edit page, the problem is that if I leave the email so it tells me that the email has already been used. I don't know how to solve.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkemaill() == true)
        {

            Label35.Visible = true;
            Label35.Text = "Questa email è già stata usata";
        }
          else if (Partitaiva() == true)
         {
            Label36.Visible = true;
            Label36.Text = "La partita iva già è stata usata";
         }
          else
          {
            string query = "UPDATE Persona SET Email = @Email, 
            RagioneSociale = @RagioneSociale, Piva = @Piva WHERE ID = 
            @id";
            using (SqlConnection con = new 
            SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                List<SqlParameter> p = new List<SqlParameter>();
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", TextBox12.Text));
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@RagioneSociale", 
                TextBox11.Text));
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@Piva", TextBox14.Text));
                p.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", Id));
                con.Open();
                GetExample(cmd, p.ToArray());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                Response.Redirect("Dash.aspx");
             }
        }
    }
```

this is the function, the other I do not put it because it is the same as this:

```
    private Boolean checkemail()
    {
        Boolean emailavailable = false;
        String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-LORL4DL;Initial 
        Catalog=Databasepersone;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        String myquery = "Select Email from Persona where Email='" + 
        TextBox12.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = myquery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            emailavailable = true;
        }
        con.Close();
        return emailavailable;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your query becomes `Select Email from Persona where Email=''`, which returns zero records, indicating that the empty email address is available, allowing your code to continue.

You need to validate your user input. Use the `RequiredFieldValidator`, for example, see [How to validate this data entry form in ASP.NET Web Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827443/how-to-validate-this-data-entry-form-in-asp-net-web-forms) and [Microsoft Docs: RequiredFieldValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator?view=netframework-4.8). This makes sure that your code isn't executed when the email textbox is empty.

For the other problem, if you want to check whether *another* user has the same email address, you need to add the current user's ID:

```
SELECT Email FROM Persona WHERE Email = @Email AND Id != @Id
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. And you shouldn't hardcode your connection string.

Comment: no you did not understand the problem is that in the edit page if I want to leave the email as it was I do not do it I have to change it because it tells me that has already been used

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
   private Boolean checkemail(string _email)
   {
        bool emailavailable = false;

        using (your context)
        {
            var res = context.Persona.Where(p => p.Email == _email).ToList();

            if (res != null)
            emailavailable = true;
        }
        return emailavailable;
    }
```

Comment: This is EF context